# leap years and R programming

Tags: r

I want to write a function that returns leap years in the specified duration of years. But my code returns the results as a logical vector. what can I do get the result in numeric vector like for the below code the result should be "c(2000,2004,2008)"

```
    "ans<- function(year1, year2)
 {return(((c(year1:year2) %% 4 == 0) & (c(year1:year2) %% 100 != 0)) | (c(year1:year2) %% 400 == 0)); return(c(year1:year2))}"

 ans(2000,2010)
```

> TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

Comment: This is a different question as it used to check leap years between any given duration of years and not just the assigned ones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just needs a slight modification:

```
ans<- function(year1, year2){
  return(c(year1:year2)[((c(year1:year2) %% 4 == 0) & (c(year1:year2) %% 100 != 0)) | (c(year1:year2) %% 400 == 0)])}

> ans(2000, 2010)
[1] 2000 2004 2008
```